# NPM request form keeps returning 415 status

Tags: javascript, node.js, request, content-type, npm-request

I am trying to make a simple request that was successful in Postman. It's just a POST action with a static URL, `Content-Type` is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, and two form fields. As simple as this mock example:

[image]

However, I can't get the same request working using NPM Request with form:

```
var apiUrl = "https://myapp.com/myendpoint";
const formData = {
    "user_type": "simple_user",
    "api_key": "123456789XYZ"
}

try {
    request.post({url:apiUrl, formData:formData}, function(err, res, result){
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
        else {
            console.log(res.statusCode); //always 415
            console.log(result); //always undefined
        }
    });
} catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
}
```

According to the [documentation](https://github.com/request/request#forms), I am doing it the right way. Can someone point me to what's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documentation the `formData` key should be `form`.

Try the below:

```
try {
    request.post({url:apiUrl, form:formData}, function(err, res, result){
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
        else {
            // You should have a good response here
        }
    });
} catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
}
```

Comment: That's strange, in the link to the doc, they used `formData ` instead of `form`, maybe the doc needs to be fixed

Comment: I think you might be confusing it with [multipart/form-data (Multipart FormUploads)](https://github.com/request/request#multipartform-data-multipart-form-uploads) - for multipart forms it expects `formData`. For `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` it expects `form`